# Intercepting click on send in Mail.app

Tags: cocoa, email, intercept, osx-leopard

Is it possible to intercept click on Send in Mac OS X Mail application?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically it can be done by using `Accessibility APIs`. I listen to moue click events in my application, so when I get a click I check whether the `Mail.app` is a frontmost application and whether a click came from Send button `UIElement`.

Comment: Do you know how to cancel the click event? Thanks.

Comment: If you anyway catch clicks and you have a handler, that does the evaluation of click events, just return something that indicates, that the click was processed in the case you checked and found that it was Send button. I mean don't pass the click event to system for execution.

Answer (score 2):

You can, but it won't necessarily be easy. You should be able to inject some code into the program (see for example [SIMBL](http://www.culater.net/software/SIMBL/SIMBL.php) and [F-Script Anywhere](http://pmougin.wordpress.com/2010/01/05/the-revenge-of-f-script-anywhere/)) and then change the button's target.